# Open Specific Event logs using win32evtlog Python

Tags: python, pywin32

I want to open a specific log to the Windows Event Log, named "Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager". I used this code:

```
import win32evtlog

server = 'localhost' # name of the target computer to get event logs
logtype = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\System\Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager'
hand = win32evtlog.OpenEventLog(server,logtype)
flags =  win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_SEQUENTIAL_READ|win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_FORWARDS_READ
total = win32evtlog.GetNumberOfEventLogRecords(hand)

while True:
    events = win32evtlog.ReadEventLog(hand, flags,0)
    if events:
        for event in events:
                print('Event Category:', event.EventCategory)
                print ('Time Generated:', event.TimeGenerated)
                print ('Source Name:', event.SourceName)
                print ('Event ID:', event.EventID)
                print ('Event Type:', event.EventType)
                data = event.StringInserts
                if data:
                    print('Event Data:')
                    for msg in data:
                        print(msg)
```

But it doesn't work, this code open "System" log, instead "Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager".
Why it doesn't work? And if it is not a bug, but a feature, what is the way to read this log?

Thanks to your answer

Comment: For me, it reads from "system" instead of "forwarded events"

Comment: Maybe you are running into this bug https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/676 . The solution is to use the newer Evt* functions. As stated https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2012-May/012292.html . I have not tested anything as I don't use windows. Just googled a bit. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use first level subkeys like `Application`, `HardwareEvents`, `Internet Explorer`, `System` etc..

> **sourceName** specifies the name of the source that the returned handle will reference. The source name must be a subkey of a logfile entry under the EventLog key in the registry. [win32evtlog.OpenEventLog](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32evtlog__OpenEventLog_meth.html)

> If you specify a custom log and it cannot be found, the event logging service opens the Application log; however, there will be no associated message or category string file. [OpenEventLogA function (winbase.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-openeventloga)

However you can use `win32evtlog.EvtQuery` function for fetching events.

Note: If you get `Access Denied` error, try to run with `Run as Administrator`

```py
import win32evtlog
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# open event file
query_handle = win32evtlog.EvtQuery(
    'C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager%4Operational.evtx',
    win32evtlog.EvtQueryFilePath)

read_count = 0
while True:
    # read 100 records
    events = win32evtlog.EvtNext(query_handle, 100)
    read_count += len(events)
    # if there is no record break the loop
    if len(events) == 0:
        break
    for event in events:
        xml_content = win32evtlog.EvtRender(event, win32evtlog.EvtRenderEventXml)
        # print(xml_content)

        # parse xml content
        xml = ET.fromstring(xml_content)
        # xml namespace, root element has a xmlns definition, so we have to use the namespace
        ns = '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event}'

        event_id = xml.find(f'.//{ns}EventID').text
        level = xml.find(f'.//{ns}Level').text
        channel = xml.find(f'.//{ns}Channel').text
        execution = xml.find(f'.//{ns}Execution')
        process_id = execution.get('ProcessID')
        thread_id = execution.get('ThreadID')
        time_created = xml.find(f'.//{ns}TimeCreated').get('SystemTime')
        print(f'Time: {time_created}, Level: {level} Event Id: {event_id}, Channel: {channel}, Process Id: {process_id}, Thread Id: {thread_id}')
        
        user_data = xml.find(f'.//{ns}UserData')
        # user_data has possible any data
        
print(f'Read {read_count} records')
```

Output:

```
Time: 2020-12-20T10:47:53.3790439Z, Level: 4 Event Id: 32, Channel: Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager/Operational, Process Id: 1476, Thread Id: 1496
Time: 2020-12-20T10:47:57.5636553Z, Level: 4 Event Id: 41, Channel: Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager/Operational, Process Id: 1476, Thread Id: 1504
Time: 2020-12-20T10:47:57.5662431Z, Level: 4 Event Id: 42, Channel: Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager/Operational, Process Id: 1476, Thread Id: 1504
Time: 2020-12-20T10:48:26.9395585Z, Level: 4 Event Id: 21, Channel: Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager/Operational, Process Id: 1476, Thread Id: 1512
Time: 2020-12-20T10:48:27.0466986Z, Level: 4 Event Id: 22, Channel: Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager/Operational, Process Id: 1476, Thread Id: 10212
Read 823 records
```