# How can I get windows EventLog with python?

Tags: python, events, pywin32, event-log, win32con

How  can get log from this path : Application and service -> microsoft ->windows -> ...

like This [Eventlog path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGxOj.jpg)

I wrote this code but it did not work for this path
I also get the logtype ... from  in eventlog

```
    server = 'localhost' # name of the target computer to get event logs
    logtype = "Microsoft-Windows-Dhcp-Client/Admin" # 'Application' # 'Security' #'System'
    hand = we.OpenEventLog(None,logtype)
    flags = we.EVENTLOG_FORWARDS_READ|we.EVENTLOG_SEQUENTIAL_READ
    while True:
            events = we.ReadEventLog(hand, flags,0)
            if events:
                for event in events:
                   Source_Name  = event.SourceName
```

Comment: I used evtx library, if there is another method, thank you for your help.

Comment: This question has been answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62173180/open-specific-event-logs-using-win32evtlog-python Shortly it says that you need to read log in XML format and parse them.

Comment: @kaco I also used the method you mentioned and it had problems, including when there are too many logs  **EvtNext**  can not support well and I solved my problem with **evtx.Evtx**.