# Create a Windows Event listener with win32evtlog

Tags: python, winapi, event-handling, listener, pywin32

I am trying to develop a listener for the Windows event log. It should wait until anything new is added and when this happens it should catch the new event and pass it as an object so I can create a handler. I have found some things online but nothing has worked so far. I am using win32evtlog and win32event.

The code I have so far is this:

```
import win32evtlog 
import win32event

server = 'localhost' # name of the target computer to get event logs
logtype = 'Application' # 'Application' # 'Security'
hand = win32evtlog.OpenEventLog(server,logtype)
flags = win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_BACKWARDS_READ|win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_SEQUENTIAL_READ
total = win32evtlog.GetNumberOfEventLogRecords(hand)
print(total)
h_evt = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 1, 0, "evt0")

for x in range(10):
    notify = win32evtlog.NotifyChangeEventLog(hand, h_evt)
    wait_result = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(h_evt, win32event.INFINITE)
    print("notify", notify)
```

The output after I run it and force one event to happen is this:

```
865
notify None
```

After this it gets stuck and does not catch any other events.
**Thank you in advance for any help**

Answer (score 0):

I noticed 2 things. First, you create a manual reset event, but never reset it. Second, you should only need to call `win32evtlog.NotifyChangeEventLog` once.

```
import win32evtlog 
import win32event
import win32api

server = 'localhost' # name of the target computer to get event logs
logtype = 'MyAppSource'
hand = win32evtlog.OpenEventLog(server, logtype)
flags = win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_FORWARDS_READ | win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_SEQUENTIAL_READ
total = win32evtlog.GetNumberOfEventLogRecords(hand)
print(total)
total += 1

h_evt = win32event.CreateEvent(None, False, False, "evt0")
notify = win32evtlog.NotifyChangeEventLog(hand, h_evt)

for x in range(10):
    wait_result = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(h_evt, win32event.INFINITE)
    readlog = win32evtlog.ReadEventLog(hand, flags, total)
    for event in readlog:
        print(f"{event.TimeGenerated.Format()} : [{event.RecordNumber}] : {event.SourceName}")
    total += len(readlog)

win32evtlog.CloseEventLog(hand)
win32api.CloseHandle(h_evt)
```

You can change `MyAppSource` to your source name. For example, on my computer I have:
[image]

If I want to monitor "Dell", for example: `logtype = 'Dell'`

---

The method above will only work for first level sources. If you want to go to a deeper level, use `win32evtlog.EvtSubscribe()`. Here, I use it with a callback - borrowing the xml code from the answer linked to in the comments.

```
import win32evtlog
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

channel = 'Microsoft-Windows-Windows Defender/Operational'

def on_event(action, context, event_handle):
    if action == win32evtlog.EvtSubscribeActionDeliver:
        xml = ET.fromstring(win32evtlog.EvtRender(event_handle, win32evtlog.EvtRenderEventXml))
        # xml namespace, root element has a xmlns definition, so we have to use the namespace
        ns = '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event}'

        event_id = xml.find(f'.//{ns}EventID').text
        level = xml.find(f'.//{ns}Level').text
        channel = xml.find(f'.//{ns}Channel').text
        execution = xml.find(f'.//{ns}Execution')
        process_id = execution.get('ProcessID')
        thread_id = execution.get('ThreadID')
        time_created = xml.find(f'.//{ns}TimeCreated').get('SystemTime')
        print(f'Time: {time_created}, Level: {level} Event Id: {event_id}, Channel: {channel}, Process Id: {process_id}, Thread Id: {thread_id}')
        print(xml.find(f'.//{ns}Data').text)
        print()

handle = win32evtlog.EvtSubscribe(
    channel,
    win32evtlog.EvtSubscribeToFutureEvents,
    None,
    Callback = on_event)

# Wait for user to hit enter...
input()

win32evtlog.CloseEventLog(handle)
```

Comment: If you need an auto-reset event, why avoid using an auto-reset event?

Comment: @IInspectable Sure, makes sense. Just showing how to use a manual event.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I think the win32event.INFINITE time is blocking the listener, if I change it I think it is catching everything
EDIT: nope, that doesn't fix it, just makes it read backwards I think 

Comment: Maybe that's the intention. What the code does show is how to do it wrong. Consider what's happening when the system sets the event in between the code reading and formatting log entries and before the code resetting the event.

Comment: @IInspectable Microsoft's example code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/eventlog/receiving-event-notification) uses a manual reset event.

Comment: @teresa Yes, `win32event.INFINITE` will make it block forever or until the event is set. If you want to change it to a timeout, you will need to check the return value to see what happened: a timeout or an event.

Comment: Copying a bug still makes it a bug.

Comment: @IInspectable Ok. Using Microsoft's logic can lead to missing some triggers if there is an event between `WaitForSingleObject` and `ResetEvent`. Updated answer. Note, the code will eventually list those missed messages in the read loop when some later event fires. It's just that there may be a delay.

Comment: @Johnny Mopp I just need a way to get the events (manual or automatic is fine as long as it works) also realised I need to access the Applications and Services Logs folder instead of the normal Windows logs directory, so as I read, I would need to use different functions (Evt* ones that are more recent). Do you have any tips/help on how to do this?

Comment: @teresa I have changed the code a bit. If you want to monitor a specific source under the "Applications and Services Logs" folder, replace `'MyAppSource'` with your source name.

Comment: @Johnny Mopp The Dell example works however I am trying to access a specific folder and when I add the path it defaults back to 'Windows Logs/Application'. I want to access the Firewall logs that is located in 'Applications and Service Logs/Microsoft/Windows/Windows Defender/Operational' but I cannot find a way to do this

Comment: I tried that one and it still defaults to Application

Comment: when inspecting the log, the complete path that appears on the properties is `%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\Microsoft-Windows-Windows Defender%4Operational.evtx` and the full name is `Microsoft-Windows-Windows Defender/Operational` but none work either

Comment: There is some help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62173180/open-specific-event-logs-using-win32evtlog-python) but I can't seem to be able to make in both access the right log AND be a listener instead of a simple access

Comment: @teresa Finally got some time to look at this. See updated answer.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thank you for all the help!!!I have another question though 
Is it possible to subscribe to several paths at the same time? would I need some type of multi processing? Also, can I use this new method to access the default logs? Now, when I try to access Windows Logs/Security for example, it says that access is denied. Thank you again for all the help